# Ruby string#crypt in c# and php

Tags: c#, php, ruby, string, crypt

I have a ruby client program that encrypts a password with string#crypt like so

```
  encrypted = password.crypt(SALT)
  # removing first two characters which actually are the salt for safety
  return encrypted[2, encrypted.size - 2]
```

it then sends it to a server for comparison with it's stored pre-encrypted string.
how ever I need to be able to send the same encrypted password form a c# app and a php web page and still be able to log in with the same password from any of the other clients.

what would be the equivalent code in C# and php for the encryption?

Answer (score 6):

**C**

- [crypt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt)

  > crypt() is the password encryption function. It is based on the Data Encryption Standard algorithm with variations intended (among other things) to discourage use of hardware implementations of a key search.
  >
  > key is a user's typed password.
  >
  > salt is a two-character string chosen from the set [a-zA-Z0-9./]. This string is used to perturb the algorithm in one of 4096 different ways.

**Ruby**

- [crypt](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/crypt)

  > Applies a one-way cryptographic hash to str by invoking the standard library function crypt. The argument is the salt string, which should be two characters long, each character drawn from [a-zA-Z0-9./].

**PHP**

- [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

  > crypt() will return an encrypted string using the standard Unix DES-based encryption algorithm or alternative algorithms that may be available on the system.

**Python**

- [crypt.crypt](http://docs.python.org/library/crypt.html)

  > This module implements an interface to the crypt(3) routine, which is a one-way hash function based upon a modified DES algorithm;

**C#**

The .NET Framework doesn't include an API for the Unix *crypt* function, but here are some libraryies that provide implementations:

- [CryptAPI](http://cryptapi.sourceforge.net/)

  > CryptAPI is a C# library that contains unimplemented algorithms in the .NET framework (NT, NTLM, BlowFish, DES and MD5) linking and emulating the crypt() unix function re-programmed in C#. The main purpose is to provide backward compatiblity.
- [A C# implementation of Unix crypt()](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/unixcrypt.aspx)